# LyX/LaTeX widetilde with superscripts problem

Tags: lyx, superscripts, tilde

Using the \widetilde command to denote a tilde on a letter usually works wonders, although the tilde needs to be slightly lowered in my opinion. This didn't bother me too terribly until I needed to use it in a superscript:
[image]

Is there some way to lower the tilde sign in LyX? The \tilde command is lower in superscripts (although still too high in the rest of the equation) but provides an unsatisfactory tilde.

Comment: You say you use lyx. Can you please post a minimal example? (See for instance http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample .)

Answer (score 1):

You have to load `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\frac{E}{A}=\dot{\widetilde{x}}^2+e^{-2\widetilde{x}}-2e^{-\widetilde{x}} \\
\frac{V}{A}=e^{-2\widetilde{x}}-e^{2\widetilde{x}}\approx -1+\widetilde{x}^2
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The reason is that without `amsmath`, the math extension font is loaded at a fixed size, so the wide tilde in superscripts is the same as the one for normal size.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't seem to work, as the package was already loaded beforehand. It could be related to my Document Class being Hebrew Article.

Comment: @FishyFod Sorry, but I can't say more than this. Check the package `amsmath` is indeed loaded and ***without*** the `cmex10` option.